# Again the probability of being a triangle's side lengths

Tags: probability

I have seen several questions in math stack exchange concerning the probability that three numbers are the lengths of a triangle. Now, what is the probability if the three numbers are integers selected randomly from among $1, 2, \dots n$, where $n$ is a given positive integer.

Comment: Could you include links / ref of these "several questions"?

Comment: Do the side lengths have to be distinct? [ie are you picking with replacement or not]

Comment: The numbers are arbitrarily selected.

Comment: So $(1,2,3),$ $(1,1,2),$ $(1,1,1),$ $(2,1,1),$ and $(2,3,1)$ are all equally likely to be selected? Or are there only three distinct outcomes in that list and each is equally likely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $a_n$ of triples $(x,y,z)\in[n]^3$ forming the edge lengths of a nondegenerate triangle is given by
$$a_n={1\over2}(n^3+n)\ .\tag{1}$$
The sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq1}=(1, 5, 15, 34, 65, 111, 175, 260, 369, 505,\ldots)$ is referenced as [A006003](http://oeis.org/A006003) at OEIS, where there is made a reference to the question at hand. The required probability $p_n$ then is $$p_n={a_n\over n^3}={1\over2}+{1\over 2n^2}\ .$$

In order to obtain $(1)$ one sets up a recursion for $a_n$: This number is equal to $a_{n-1}$ plus the number of admissible triples having $3$, $2$, or $1$ edges of length $n$ and the other edges of lengths $\leq n-1$. One obtains
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+1+3\cdot(n-1)+3\cdot{(n-2)(n-1)\over2}\ ,$$
from which $(1)$ easily follows, using that $a_1=1$.